# How do I use functions like this? ( C++, operator overloading)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class VectorND
{
public:
    int N;
    VectorND(int n)
        :N(n) {}

    float *vec_value = new float[N];

    void assignValue(int i, float v)
        {
            vec_value[i] = v;
        }

};
```

This is my code and I'm trying to solve this problem,
 but I do not know what to do.

> Problem 4. Implement operator overloading of VectorND class for the
>   following operations.
>
> ```
> my_vec.assignValue(3) = 10;
>
> std::cout << my_vec(3);
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```
> int main(void)
> {
>   VectorND my_vec(10);
>     my_vec.assignValue(3) = 10;
>     std::cout << my_vec(3);
>
>     return 0;
> }
>
> Output : 10
> ```

Comment: You have to overload the function call operator.

Comment: When are you expecting that`new` to be called?

Comment: I've read the explanation of operator overloading, but I do not know how to apply it to this problem.

Comment: my_vec.assignValue(3) = 10;

Comment: I can not do this part in particular.

Comment: @DW7 in my answer it shows you.

Comment: @DW7 _"I've read the explanation of operator overloading, but I do not know how to apply it to this problem."_ You're right in so far that the function call operator syntax is poorly covered in that Q&A I proposed as duplicate. I'll edit the relevant part.

Comment: @DW7 I hope [that's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/8242698) clearer now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the first operator overload you have to do something like this:

```
float& operator () (int i)
{
    return vec_value[i];
}
```

When you do `myVec(3) = 4;`, the `myVec(3)` returns a reference to the float at the index 3 which you then assign to 4.

For `myVec.assign(3) = 10` you should overload the assign method to take an index and return a reference to a float for that index.

For the second one it is more complicated you have to do a declaration in your class `friend ostream& operator << (ostream& n, VectorND& myVec);`

Then outside the class:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& n, const VectorND& myVec)
{
   // This just pushes all the values to the stream
   for(int i = 0; i< N; i++) cout<<vec_value[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `VectorND& myVec` should be `const VectorND& myVec` in the output operator overload.

Comment: @user0042 You are right that is the best practice

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate it.
You're the god of coding.

Comment: If it works don't forget to upvote and accept @DW7

Comment: @JakeFreeman You should have better gone my course of action here.

Comment: @user0042 I used your suggestion and I recognize that it was correct.

Comment: @JakeFreeman No, no. I meant you should have rather improved the answer in the duplicate instead of writing a new one.

Comment: @user0042 my answer is the only one for this question, I guess I am not understanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: @JakeFreeman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728965/how-do-i-use-functions-like-this-c-operator-overloading/47729100?noredirect=1#comment82419084_47728965

Comment: Ok I will edit the original to incorporate this @user0042